# iOS error unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6ea9090

Tags: core-data, ios5, storyboard

I used core data to set up all of my entities. But when I try to create a new customer entity and send it to the modal addCustomer view controller I keep getting this error.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController
>   setCustomer:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8854700'

The error occurs in AccountListTableViewController.m when the program gets to addController.customer = newCustomer in the prepareForSegue.

Here is the code:

AccountListTableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CustomerAddViewController.h"
@class Customer;


@interface AccountListTableViewController : UITableViewController <CustomerAddDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> {
@private
    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;



@end
```

AccountListTableViewController.m

```
#import "AccountListTableViewController.h"
#import "AccountListCell.h"
#import "Customer.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"



@implementation AccountListTableViewController

@synthesize managedObjectContext, fetchedResultsController;

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"AddAccountSegue"] ) {
        CustomerAddViewController *addController = [segue destinationViewController];
        addController.delegate = self;

        Customer *newCustomer = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Customer" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        addController.customer = newCustomer;
    }
}

-(void)customerAddViewController:(CustomerAddViewController *)customerAddViewController didAddCustomer:(Customer *)customer{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    //I added this to keep from crashing
    if (managedObjectContext == nil) 
    { 
        managedObjectContext = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
        NSLog(@"After managedObjectContext: %@",  managedObjectContext);
    }
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
//#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
//#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];

    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    //Customer *customer = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    AccountListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AccountCellReuseIdentifier"];
    Customer *aCustomer = (Customer *)[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.customer = aCustomer;

//    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
//    
//    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
//    if (cell == nil) {
//        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
//    }

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     */
}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    // Set up the fetched results controller if needed.
    if (fetchedResultsController == nil) {
        // Create the fetch request for the entity.
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Customer" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

        // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lastName" ascending:YES];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

        // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
        // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
        NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
        aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
        self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

//        [aFetchedResultsController release];
//        [fetchRequest release];
//        [sortDescriptor release];
//        [sortDescriptors release];
    }

    return fetchedResultsController;
}    


/**
 Delegate methods of NSFetchedResultsController to respond to additions, removals and so on.
 */

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    // The fetch controller is about to start sending change notifications, so prepare the table view for updates.
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

//      case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
//          [self configureCell:(AccountListCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
//          break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    // The fetch controller has sent all current change notifications, so tell the table view to process all updates.
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

@end
```

CustomerAddViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Customer.h"
@class Customer;
@protocol CustomerAddDelegate;

@interface CustomerAddViewController : UITableViewController{

    Customer *customer;

    UITextField *firstName;
    UITextField *lastName;
    UITextField *address;
    UITextField *city;
    UITextField *state;
    UITextField *zip;
    UITextField *homePhone;
    UITextField *cellPhone;
    UITextField *email;
    id <CustomerAddDelegate> delegate;

}
@property (nonatomic, strong) Customer *customer;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *firstName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *lastName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *address;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *city;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *state;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *zip;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *homePhone;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *cellPhone;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *email;

@property (nonatomic, strong) id <CustomerAddDelegate> delegate;

- (IBAction) saveCustomer;
- (IBAction) cancel;
@end

@protocol CustomerAddDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)customerAddViewController:(CustomerAddViewController *)customerAddViewController didAddCustomer:(Customer *)customer;

@end
```

CustomerAddView.m

```
#define NAME 0
#define ADDRESS 1
#define CONTACT 2
#import "CustomerAddViewController.h"
#import "Customer.h"


@implementation CustomerAddViewController

@synthesize firstName, lastName, address, city, state, zip, homePhone, cellPhone, email, customer, delegate;

//- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
//{
//    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
//    if (self) {
//        // Custom initialization
//    }
//    return self;
//}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   // [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

//This stuff not needed because we are setting static sections and rows in storyboard

//- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
//{
//    return 3;
//}
//
//- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
//{
//    NSInteger rows = 0;
//    switch (section) {
//        case NAME:
//            rows = 2;
//            break;
//        case ADDRESS:
//            rows = 4;
//            break;
//        case CONTACT:
//            rows = 3;
//            break;
//    }
//
//    return rows;
//}

//- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
//{
//    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
//    
//    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
//    if (cell == nil) {
//        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
//    }
//    
//    // Configure the cell...
//    
//    return cell;
//}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     */
}

@end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
CustomerAddViewController *addController = [segue destinationViewController];
```

Are you sure your destination view controller is a `CustomerAddViewController`?

It looks like it's actually a navigation controller. Hence the `[UINavigationController setCustomer:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8854700` when you do `addController.customer = newCustomer`

Comment: So the first item in the storyboard that I am using with that segue is a navigation controller. I created the tableview controller and then used the embed navigation controller. How would I get around this so that I message the table controller instead of the navigation controller?

Comment: Is your AccountListTableViewController in a navigation controller? If so, your CustomerAddViewController shouldn't be in its own nav controller, as it will will get pushed onto the first nav controller when the segue happens.

Comment: The CustomerAddViewController is presented modally, I should have mentioned that sorry. If I remove the embedded nav controller on CustomerAddViewController it runs fine but there isn't a nav bar for done or cancel buttons.

Comment: The nav controller's root view controller should be your CustomerAddViewController, so when you get the destination view controller (the nav controller), try `CustomerAddViewController *addController = [[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];`

Comment: That worked, thanks! Now I just have the warning Incompatible pointer types initializing 'CustomerAddViewController *__strong' with an expression of type 'UIViewController *'

Comment: Are you creating your CustomerAddViewController in the storyboard? If so, when you look at its Identity Inspector, is the Class set to CustomerAddViewController? And if you click the nav controller, then check its Connections Inspector, is RelationShip - rootViewController set to Customer Add View Controller?

Comment: I have the class set to CustomerAddViewController and the RelationShip - rootViewController is set to Customer Add View Controller for the nav controller.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is casting it: `CustomerAddViewController *addController = (CustomerAddViewController *)[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];`

Comment: That took care of it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

In continuation to the first answer, the correct way to then reach the destination view controller when a navigation controller is between is as follows

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AddAccountSegue"])        
    {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        CustomerAddViewController *addController = (id)[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
        [addController setCustomer:yourObject];
    }
}
```